# Bing maps WP7 performance

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Is there a way to improve bingmaps performance when there are custom pushpins on it?
I'am already clustering the pushpins, meaning I'm not drawing those which are outside the rectangle, not drawing those which are on top on one another, but still the performance, is nowhere near the performance of the embedded bingmaps.

Comment: Are you testing this in an emulator or a device?

Comment: If that's the case, looking at the specification of an embedded device compared to WP7. Embedded device has a better specifications, thus makes it more faster. So comparing the WP7's performance to embedded doesn't make any sense. I would suggest that you could try to figure out how to minimize the performance that is required to use custom pushpin but ends with the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

SmaartMobile, take a look at the series from AwkwardCoder : http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-many-pins-can-bing-maps-handle-in.html it has much tips/tricks.

Small question, any blogpost from you, how you handeled the clustering?

Comment: I will check it out, thanks, when it work I mark your answer.